# Probability of a fit at a bridge table given certain conditions

Tags: probability, combinatorics

At a bridge table, West has exactly five cards in the heart suit while North has three. Knowing this, what is the probability that North and his partner South have a fit, i.e. a suit in which they together hold  at least eight cards ?

A more mathematical presentation would go like this : start with a 52-element set $C$ (the set of all $C$ards). Fix a partition $C=S_1\cup S_2\cup S_3\cup S_4$ into four 13-element sets (each $S_k$ is a $S$uit), and then the probability universe $\Omega$ is the set of all (ordered) partitions of $C$ into four 13-element sets, in particular $|\Omega|=\binom{4\times 13}{13}\times\binom{3\times 13}{13}\times\binom{2\times 13}{13}$. The question is then to compute $P_{I}(E)$, where $I,E$ are the events defined by 
$$I:|A_1\cap P_1|=5,|A_2\cap P_1|=3,$$
$$E:\exists k\ |A_2\cap P_k|+|A_3\cap P_k| \geq 8$$

My thoughts : if we put $x=|A_3\cap P_1|$, we have $\binom{13}{5}\times\binom{3\times 13}{13-5}$ possibilities for $A_1$, $\binom{13-5}{3}\times\binom{2\times 13+5}{13-3}$ possibilities for $A_2$, and $\binom{13-8}{x}\times\binom{13+8}{13-x}$ possibilities for $A_3$, so that

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
|I| &=& \binom{13}{5}\times\binom{3\times 13}{13-5}\times
\binom{13-5}{3}\times\binom{2\times 13+5}{13-3}\times\sum_{x=0}^{5}\binom{13-8}{x}\times\binom{13+8}{13-x} \\
&=& \binom{13}{5}\times\binom{39}{8}\times
\binom{8}{3}\times\binom{31}{10}\times\sum_{x=0}^{5}\binom{5}{x}\times\binom{21}{13-x} \\
&=& 2045420370655680977902944000 
\end{array}
$$

I tried a similar analysis for $|I\cap E|$ but found nothing useful.

Comment: Do you want the probability of a North-South fit only in hearts, or do you want the probability of a fit in _any_ suit?

Comment: The systematic/general way to do this: Note that you already know there are 8 hearts and 26 - 8 = 18 non-hearts among 2 hands of 26 cards. The number of hearts in one of the remaining hand will follow a hypergeometric distribution, so you sum the pmf. In bridge term you are seeking a specific 3-2 + 4-1 + 5-0 breaks. By symmetry it is just one half.

Comment: @Ewan Delanoy -- Also, you say a fit is a majority of the cards in a suit, but wouldn't that be at least $7$ cards, rather than at least $8$?

Comment: From bridge experience, I think "at least eight" is the intended question, and "a majority" is a mistake.

Comment: @GregMartin you are absolutely right. Corrected, thanks.

Comment: @quasi answer to your first question : I want the probability of a fit in any suit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With 44 remaining cards and 23 left to give North+South the sample space is ${44\choose23}$

Because we can make multiple fits we will count the number of non-fit hands and use the inverse.

We'll start by dividing the deck by suit into piles of 5,13,13,13. We'll then select 0-4,0-7,0-7,0-7 cards from each pile to make 23 total.

This "puzzle" is actually quite restrictive. The minimum number of hearts we can choose is not 0 but 2. If we take 2 our remaining choices are forced: we must then take 7,7,7 from each remaining pile. So "2777" is one "pile distribution" option and results in:

${5\choose2}{13\choose7}{13\choose7}{13\choose7}$ possible hands

What others?

If we take 3 hearts then we can do "3677", "3767", or "3776". Each of these 3 permutations results in the same number of potential hands so given 2 hearts the number of potential hands will be:

$3*{5\choose3}{13\choose6}{13\choose7}{13\choose7}$

Finally, if we take 4 hearts we can do 4577 (3 permutations) or 4667 (3 permutations) and the number of potential hands will be:

$3*{5\choose4}{13\choose5}{13\choose7}{13\choose7}+3*{5\choose4}{13\choose6}{13\choose6}{13\choose7}$

So, the total number of non-fit hands is:

${5\choose2}{13\choose7}{13\choose7}{13\choose7}+3*{5\choose3}{13\choose6}{13\choose7}{13\choose7}+3*{5\choose4}{13\choose5}{13\choose7}{13\choose7}+3*{5\choose4}{13\choose6}{13\choose6}{13\choose7}=334763217360$

Taking the inverse we find the probability of making any fit hand:

$({44\choose23}-334763217360)/{44\choose23}=48888496/58642669\approx0.83$

Comment: Thank you for your helpful contribution. It is incorrect as stated however : $\binom{44}{23}$ only counts which cards are in the North-South team, it does not take into account which are in North's hand and which are with South's hand.  And this matters, as we know that North has three hearts

Comment: @EwanDelanoy why does that matter? isn't the definition of a fit based on the team's holdings? if we're told which 23 cards will be dealt to the team shouldn't that alone determine the presence of a fit?

Comment: On what grounds could you claim that the fact that North has three hearts plays no role ? What we have here is a conditional probability, with a condition and a conditioned event. You only see the conditioned event and forget all about the condition

Comment: yes, i don't care that north has 3 hearts. i care only that the team has 3 hearts. the probability shouldn't change if north had only 2 but south had 1 or north had 1 but south had 2. unless i'm missing something about the rules of bridge.

Comment: To take an extreme example, if the condition was that North has all thirteen spades, the answer would definitely not be the 0.83 you found. You could say you don't care, but the real world would care.

Comment: hold on: before going any further here can you confirm the definition of  fit. if north has 3 hearts and south has 5 hearts, is there a fit? if north has 0 hearts and south has 8 hearts, is there a fit?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57954/discussion-between-ewan-delanoy-and-abovestand).

Comment: Working it out independently, I got the exact same result
$$\frac{48888496}{58642669}$$
as Abovestand.

Comment: @quasi care to post your derivation? i thought i was on the right track but then realized OP states "exactly" 3 and 5, not "at least". the above method is counting fits made, for example, when north holds 4 hearts and south holds 4 hearts...

Comment: @Abovestand: My reasoning is almost identical to yours, but I'll post it (to add confirmation of yours) when I get a chance.

Comment: Also, a simulation with $10^6$ deals of a random deck with 8 hearts removed convincingly matches Abovestand's numerical result.

Comment: I think I did it right. I forced exactly 3 hearts for North. But I'll check . . .

Comment: It's a _conditional_ probability. We don't have to worry about decks which would yield anything other than 5 hearts for West and 3 hearts for North.

Comment: nevermind. i'm not counting "4 north + 4 south heart fits" - i'm just counting "8 card fits". i never bothered to consider which team members would end up with which cards. this gave me some doubts when i re-read the OP but ultimately don't think it matters: we know whether a fit is present or not given which 23 cards team north/south gets - how they're distributed is another counting problem entirely and *here* we need to ensure north receives no additional hearts.

Comment: a simulation seems promising. i'd be super interested to see your derivation.

Comment: I'm convinced that your solution is correct now, and I just accepted it.

Comment: @Ewan Delanoy -- But in fact, as it turns out, that answer (as well as my previous answer) was actually _not_ correct. My new answer gets it right (I'm nearly certain).

Comment: @Abovestand -- As my revised answer indicates, your current answer and my previous answer are both incorrect. Please take a look at my revised answer (which I'm (now) fully certain is correct).

Comment: @Abovestand: Do you agree that your answer is wrong? If so, why not edit your answer to either fix it, or at least _acknowledge_ that it's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Edited to make it a bit clearer and added mathematical notation also corrected sme small math errors it now agrees with @quasi

Here we go, although this is not going to be pretty

there are 6 possibilities for the distribution of the remaining 5 hearts cards  that is south has either 0,1,2,3,4 or 5 hearts with probablities $\frac{13}{26}\frac{12}{25}\frac{11}{24}\frac{10}{23}\frac{9}{22}\binom{5}{0},\frac{13}{26}\frac{12}{25}\frac{11}{24}\frac{10}{23}\frac{13}{22}\binom{5}{1},\frac{13}{26}\frac{12}{25}\frac{11}{24}\frac{13}{23}\frac{12}{22}\binom{5}{2},\frac{13}{26}\frac{12}{25}\frac{11}{24}\frac{13}{23}\frac{12}{22}\binom{5}{2},\frac{13}{26}\frac{12}{25}\frac{11}{24}\frac{10}{23}\frac{13}{22}\binom{5}{1},\frac{13}{26}\frac{12}{25}\frac{11}{24}\frac{10}{23}\frac{9}{22}\binom{5}{0}$

(by symmetry and communativity of real numbers) 
For one of these possibilities we already have a fit for NS, namely the last one. Then we just have to calculate the chance of not a fit for the other five possibilities; for this we merge the two players of each team in to one for convenience.

in each of the five cases there are 52-13=39 cards to deal to  two sides of respectively 23(NS) 16(EW) cards 22(NS)  17(EW) cards 21(NS)  18(EW) cards 20(NS)  19(EW) cards and 19(NS)  20(EW) cards In the first two scenarios NS has to have a fit since 7*3=21. In the third scenario NS has to have 7 out of each remaning suit therefore $\binom{13}{7}^3$ is the number of combinations with no fit out of $\binom{39}{21}$. For the fourth scenario the chance of no suit is $\frac{\binom{13}{7}^2\binom{13}{6}\binom{3}{1}}{\binom{39}{20}}$.
 Finally for the fifth scenario the chance is$\frac{\binom{13}{6}^2\binom{13}{7}\binom{3}{2}+\binom{13}{7}^2\binom{13}{5}\binom{3}{1}}{\binom{39}{19}}$

summing we have the chance of not having a fit as $\frac{13}{26}\frac{12}{25}\frac{11}{24}\frac{13}{23}\frac{12}{22}\binom{5}{2}\frac{\binom{13}{7}^3}{\binom{39}{21}}+\frac{13}{26}\frac{12}{25}\frac{11}{24}\frac{13}{23}\frac{12}{22}\binom{5}{2}\frac{\binom{13}{7}^2\binom{13}{6}\binom{3}{1}}{\binom{39}{20}}+\frac{13}{26}\frac{12}{25}\frac{11}{24}\frac{10}{23}\frac{13}{22}\binom{5}{1}\frac{\binom{13}{6}^2\binom{13}{7}\binom{3}{2}+\binom{13}{7}^2\binom{13}{5}\binom{3}{1}}{\binom{39}{19}}$=0.15645669965 (or chance of a fit 0.8435433)
although I calculated that piecewise through typing it in to google(since it wouldn't let me do it directly since it is too long) and I have no better software available right now. So small errors might be from that also I might have made a small mistake somewhere but that is the asnwer I get.

Comment: @zen: Can you explain how you obtained the conditional probabilities for the $6$ possible results for the number of hearts for South? For example, how did you get 
$$\frac{13}{26}\frac{12}{25}\frac{11}{24}\frac{13}{23}\frac{12}{22}\binom{5}{2}$$
for the conditional probabilty that South gets $2$ hearts?

Comment: @quasi the first five terms is the probability that first East gets 3 hearts and South gets 2 heart after that. the first card has equal chance to go to East as it has top go to  South namely out of 26 cards that will bed dealed to East and West jointly 13 have to go to East so the chance of East receiving the first card is $\frac{13}{26}$, After the first hearts is dealed however this probability has changed. now 12 out of 25 cards left to deal will go to East so his chance of receiving the second hearts is $\frac{12}{25}$.

Comment: @quasi continued from the previous comment. Now we see that these five fractions give the chance that East gets  the first 3 cards and South the last 2. However this is just one scenario where Soutgh gets 2 hearts, Luckily all these scenarios have the same probability since all that happens is that the numerators chance places.

Comment: @quasi continued from the previous comment. In how many ways can South get 2 hearts?$\binom{5}{2}$. Therefore there are $\binom{5}{2}$ scenarios where South gets 2 hearts each with a probability of $\frac{13}{26}\frac{12}{25}\frac{11}{24}\frac{13}{23}\frac{12}{22}$. So that the probability of South having 2 hearts is  $\frac{13}{26}\frac{12}{25}\frac{11}{24}\frac{13}{23}\frac{12}{22}\binom{5}{2}$

Comment: @quasi sorry for the spelling btw , im typing this pretty fast and apparently I cannot edit my older comments. I also want to explain why the last three scenarios have the same probabilities as the first three but in reverse order. This is because they are the same probabilities seen from the perspective of East instead of South. Since these players are identical the probabilities have to be the same.

Comment: So then for the case of $2$ hearts for South, the probability can be expressed more simply as
$$
\left(
\frac
{\large{\binom{13}{3}\binom{10}{2}}}
{\large{\binom{26}{3}\binom{23}{2}}}
\right)
\binom{5}{2}$$
Yes?

Comment: Also, don't you have the wrong order for the last $3$? By symmetry, South getting $2$ hearts should have the same probability as South having $3$ hearts.

Comment: I do not think so actually, the first part of my formulation equates to $0.00161490683$ while the first of  that formulation equates to $0.01956521739$

Comment: @quasi You are right about the order, I see it now as well and do it correctly in the second part. I will fix it

Comment: Sorry, in my previous comment, I meant to write
$$
\left(
\frac
{\large{\binom{13}{3}\binom{13}{2}}}
{\large{\binom{26}{3}\binom{23}{2}}}
\right)
\binom{5}{2}$$

Not the same as your result?

Comment: @quasi no, that still gives a different value specifically $0.03391304347$

Comment: @quasi I am not sure you can write this easily with binomial coefficients

Comment: @quasi You can write it as $\frac{(13!)(13!)(21!)}{(26!)(10!)(11!)}$

Comment: Ok, let me ask a different question. In the numerator for the case where south has two hearts, I don't  undertsand the last two factors, $(13)(12)$.. Since $3$ hearts have elready been dealt. shouldn't it be $(10)(9)$?

Comment: @quasi No because three hearts have been dealt but only to east, South is yet to receive any of its 13 cards. There are 23 cards left to divide between East and South. Therefore South has a $\frac{13}{23}$ chance of receiving the next hearts. After that South still has to receive 12 cards and there are 22 cards left to divide between South and East. Since South has only received 1 card 13. Out of the 22 cards left 12 will go to South and the chance that the one remaining hearts goes to South is therefore $\frac{12}{22}$

Comment: Bythe way:
$$\frac
{(13!)(13!)(21!)}
{(26!)(10!)(11!)}
$$
is the same as
$$
\frac
{\Large{\binom{21}{10}}}
{\Large{\binom{26}{13}}}
$$

Comment: I don't follow your comment which starts with "No because three hearts have been dealt but only to east, South is yet to receive any of its 13 cards.". If three hearts have been dealt to East, there are only $23$ cards left, and only $10$ of those are hearts. So the fraction $\large{\frac{13}{23}}$ makes no sense to me. As I see it, it should be $\large{\frac{10}{23}}$.

Comment: @quasi Wait then I have done something wrong earlier.

Comment: I have to go now. See if you can resolve the issues. Let's talk again later tonight or tomorrow. What would be a good time?

Comment: @quasi your first simplification also works! sorry for the confusion. About the fraction. it is not 10 hearts that are left. it is 2 hearts that are left.first five hearts went to West then 3 to North and then 3 to East there are thus only 2 hearts left. the 13 is the number of cards that South still has to receive

Comment: @ quasi in about four hours would be fine by me. That would be 20:45 greenwhich standard

Comment: @quasi tommorow around this time is also fine by me

Comment: Ok, I see, or at least I see that it's 3 hearts and 2 hearts, not 3 hearts and 10 hearts.

Comment: Ok. I'll catch up with you one of those times, probably tomorrow.

Comment: @quasi ok great!

Comment: The conditional probability for South having $2$ hearts is just
$$
\frac
{\Large{\binom{5}{2}\binom{21}{11}}}
{\Large{\binom{26}{13}}}
$$
Explanation: Choose $2$ hearts from $5$ remaining, then choose $11$ non-hearts from $21$ remaining.

Comment: yes this is correct and equal to the value given in my answer. I first thought it was wrong but it turns out the calculation I did to check was wrong.  the answer however is correct, The formulation is simply how I thought about it when I was writing it.

Comment: I get it! (now that I can express it using binomial coefficients). Way to go! Thank you zen (+1 and + 200).

Comment: @quasi Thanks! And sorry for the unclear formulation :).

Answer (score 1):

Edit (May 19, 2017):

I'm putting a bounty ($+200$) on this question, in the hope that the dilemma can be resolved.

There are currently two answers (Abovestand's answer and mine), each with a different numerical value for the specified conditional probability. Of course, they can't both be right.

What is the correct answer?

- Abovestand's answer?

  $\qquad{\displaystyle{\frac{48888496}{58642669} \approx .8336676491}}\;\,$(as posted on Apr 29, 2017)

  My revised answer?

  $\qquad{\displaystyle{\frac{49353291017}{58507122275} \approx .8435433003}}\;\,$(as posted on May 4, 2017)

  Some other value?

I'll award the bounty to the best answer of those having at least two of the following:

- An explanation that I can follow.

  A numerical result, convincingly supported by data from a simulation.

  A consensus of support from other MSE participants.

Edit (May 25, 2017): I awarded the bounty to the user "zen".

Shown below is the answer I posted on May 4, 2017, including later edits. It retracts the answer I originally posted on May 1, 2017, gives a revised numerical result, and attempts to explain why the old answer is wrong.

Ok, here goes:

The answer I previously posted$\,-\,$on May 1, 2017, is wrong.

Sure, it matches Abovestand's answer (as posted on April 29, 2017), which was reluctantly accepted by the OP, but that answer is also wrong.

Ewan Delanoy's intuition and skepticism about that answer was correct after all!

My initial simulation was flawed in the same way.

Once I realized that my simulation was not modeling the given situation correctly, I wrote a corrected version. The corrected simulation yielded
$$\frac{8435336}{10000000} \approx .8435$$
as the frequency of a North-South fit, given the specified initial conditions$\,-\,$slightly higher than the claimed conditional probability
$$\frac{48888496}{58642669} \approx .8337$$
While that might naively appear to be a non-rejectable discrepancy, the fact is, given that the simulation used $10^7$ trials, that discrepancy is *huge*$\,-\,$it would be more than $80$ standard deviations away from the assumed mean!

The correct probability, computed via a Maple program, is exactly
$$\frac{49353291017}{58507122275} \approx .8435433003$$
matching the simulated results.

I'll leave my original flawed analysis, as shown below, to serve as an example of a flawed, but seemingly plausible solution.

Bottom line: Probability is a tricky business. Unless one is very careful, it's easy to be fooled, so if there's any doubt, one should always verify computed results via a simulation.

Shown below is the solution I previously posted. Warning: It's wrong!

It's given that the dealt hands are such that

- West gets exactly $5$ hearts.$\\[4pt]$

  North gets exactly $3$ hearts.

Let $p$ be the probability of a North-South fit in some suit.

Assuming that a "fit" in a suit means the partnership has at least $8$ cards in the given suit, I calculated
$$p = \frac{48888496}{58642669} \approx .8336676491$$
matching the answer posted by Abovestand.

My reasoning, essentially the same as Abovestand's, is as follows . . .

Let $q$ be the probability that North-South has no fit.

After dealing $5$ hearts to West, and $3$ hearts to North, there are $44$ cards remaining in the deck: $5$ remaining hearts, and $13$ from each of the non-heart suits.

Thus, there are $\small{\displaystyle{\binom{44}{23}}}$ ways to complete the hands for **NS** (the North-South partnership).

Let $q_k$  be the probability that **NS** has no fit, given that South gets $k$ hearts.

If South gets $5$ hearts, then **NS** has a fit in hearts, hence $q_5=0$.

If South gets at most $1$ heart, then **NS** gets at least $22$ non-hearts, which guarantees a fit in at least one of the non-heart suits, hence $q_0 = 0$ and $q_1 = 0$.

Thus, $q = q_2 + q_3 + q_4$.

If South gets $2$ hearts, then **NS** gets $21$ non-hearts, hence, in order to have no fit, **NS** must get exactly $7$ in each of the non-heart suits. It follows that
$$q_2 ={\large{\frac{\binom{5}{2}\binom{13}{7}^3}{\binom{44}{23}}}}
=
\frac{1472328}{58642669}
\approx
.02510676995
$$
If South gets $3$ hearts, then **NS** gets $20$ non-hearts, hence, in order to have no fit, **NS** must get $6$ in one of the non-hearts suits, and $7$ in each of the other two. It follows that
$$q_3 ={\large{\frac{\binom{5}{3}\binom{3}{1}\binom{13}{6}\binom{13}{7}^2}{\binom{44}{23}}}}
=
\frac{4416984}{58642669}
\approx
.07532030986
$$
If South gets $4$ hearts, then **NS** gets $19$ non-hearts, hence, in order to have no fit, **NS** must either get $7$ in one of the non-hearts suits, and $6$ in each of the other two, or $5$ in one of the non-hearts suits, and $7$ in each of the other two. It follows that
$$
q_4 =
{\large{
\frac{
\binom{5}{4}\binom{3}{1}
\left(
\binom{13}{7}\binom{13}{6}^2
+
\binom{13}{5}\binom{13}{7}^2
\right)
}
{
\binom{44}{23}
}
}}
=
\frac{3864861}{58642669}
\approx
.06590527113
\\[20pt]$$
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;q &= q_2 + q_3 + q_4\\[10pt]
&=\frac{1472328 + 4416984 + 3864861}{58642669}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{9754173}{58642669} \approx .1663323509\\[16pt]
\text{so}\;\;p &= 1 - q\\[8pt]
&=1- \frac{9754173}{58642669}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{48888496}{58642669} \approx .8336676491
\end{align*}
So what's wrong with the above answer?

Besides the fact that

- It fails to agree with simulation results.

  It doesn't agree with the results of a full, exact count.

where is the logical error in the reasoning?

As I see it, the error is this . . .

In the above analysis, there's nothing that forces West to get *exactly* $5$ hearts. It only forces

- North to get exactly $3$ hearts.

  The East-West partnership to get at least $5$ hearts.

Also, as I noted in one of my comments, another way to see that above solution is wrong is to consider the following simpler version of the same problem:

Take with a deck with $3$ suits$\,-\,$Hearts, Spades, and Clubs, with $4$ cards in each suit. Thus, the deck has $12$ cards, and each player is dealt $3$ cards.

Assume West gets exactly $1$ heart, and North gets exactly $2$ hearts.

Define a "fit" in a suit as a suit for which a partnership has at least $3$ cards in the suit.

If you apply the posted reasoning (which I now claim is wrong), you would get $5/7$ as the probability that North-South has a fit in at least one suit, but in fact, the correct probability is $26/35$.

Comment: Thanks again for your perseverance on a subject that interests me. But let me get this straight : you just have seemingly conflicting results between a numerical experiment and a mathematical detailed proof, and you do not know where the error lies in the proof, correct ? In such a situation I wouldn't immediately assume that the numerical experiment is correct. Can you show us your "Maple program" ?

Comment: I wrote two programs -- both complicated, independent of each other, but carefully done. The first, a sumulation, yielded the $.8435$ approximation withe $10^7$ trials. The second was a full, exact count, which yielded the fraction shown as my new answer, and it matched the simulation to $4$ decimal places.

Comment: Can you show us the code for those programs ?

Comment: But rather than trying to decipher uncommented Maple code, there's an easier way to see that the previously posted reasoning is wrong. I'll explain ...

Comment: Take the following much simpler example . . .

Comment: Take the same problem with a deck with $3$ suits, Hearts, Spades, Clubs, with $4$ cards in each suit. Thus the deck has $12$ cards. Each player is dealt $3$ cards. Assume West gets exactly $1$ Heart, and North gets exactly $2$ Hearts. Define a fit as at least $3$ cards in a suit. If you apply the originally posted reasoning, you would get $5/7$ as the probability of a North-South fit. But in fact, the correct probability is $26/35$.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving my previous answer intact, here's a revision, incorporating the key insights of zen's solution . . .

It's given that the dealt hands are such that

- West gets exactly $5$ hearts.$\\[4pt]$

  North gets exactly $3$ hearts.

Given the above,

- Let $p$ be the probability that **NS** (North-South) has a fit in some suit (at least 8 cards in the suit).$\\[4pt]$

  Let $q = 1 - p$ be the probability that **NS** has no fit.$\\[4pt]$

  Let $q_k$  be the probability that **NS** has no fit, given that South gets $k$ hearts.

If South gets $5$ hearts, then **NS** has a fit in hearts, hence $q_5=0$.

If South gets at most $1$ heart, then **NS** gets at least $22$ non-hearts, which guarantees a fit in at least one of the non-heart suits, hence $q_0 = 0$ and $q_1 = 0$.

Thus, $q = q_2 + q_3 + q_4$.

If South gets $2$ hearts, then **NS** gets $21$ non-hearts, hence, in order to have no fit, **NS** must get exactly $7$ in each of the non-heart suits. It follows that
$$q_2 =
\left(
{\large{\frac{\binom{5}{2}\binom{21}{11}}{\binom{26}{13}}}}
\right)
\!
\left(
{\large{\frac{\binom{13}{7}^3}{\binom{39}{21}}}}
\right)
=
\frac{229683168}{8358160325}
\approx
.02748011034
$$
If South gets $3$ hearts, then **NS** gets $20$ non-hearts, hence, in order to have no fit, **NS** must get $6$ in one of the non-hearts suits, and $7$ in each of the other two. It follows that
$$q_3 =
\left(
{\large{\frac{\binom{5}{3}\binom{21}{10}}{\binom{26}{13}}}}
\right)
\!
\left(
{\large{\frac{\binom{3}{1}\binom{13}{6}\binom{13}{7}^2}{\binom{39}{20}}}}
\right)
=
\frac{229683168}{3079322225}
\approx
.07458887093
$$
If South gets $4$ hearts, then **NS** gets $19$ non-hearts, hence, in order to have no fit, **NS** must either get $7$ in one of the non-hearts suits, and $6$ in each of the other two, or $5$ in one of the non-hearts suits, and $7$ in each of the other two. It follows that
$$
q_4 =
\left(
{\large{\frac{\binom{5}{4}\binom{21}{9}}{\binom{26}{13}}}}
\right)
\!
\left(
{\large{
\frac{\binom{3}{1}
\left(
\binom{13}{7}\binom{13}{6}^2
+
\binom{13}{5}\binom{13}{7}^2
\right)
}
{
\binom{39}{19}
}
}}
\right)
=
\frac{4785066}{87980635}
\approx
.05438771839
\\[20pt]$$
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;q &= q_2 + q_3 + q_4\\[10pt]
&=
\frac{229683168}{8358160325}
+
\frac{229683168}{3079322225}
+
\frac{4785066}{87980635}
\\[6pt]
&=\frac{9153831258}{58507122275} \approx .1564566997\\[16pt]
\text{so}\;\;p &= 1 - q\\[8pt]
&=1-\frac{9153831258}{58507122275}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{49353291017}{58507122275} \approx .8435433003
\end{align*}